# How to get tagbar to work with js files

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins, jsctags

If I open a file with an .html extension, tagbar works fine.

If I open a file with a .js extension, then tagbar doesn't list anything. Just renaiming the file extension to .html will make it work.

How can I get tagbar to work with .js files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [taglist-plus](https://github.com/int3/vim-taglist-plus)? It uses jsctags and it worked just fine for the brief time I had this plugin installed.

Comment: I have both taglist-plus and tagbar installed.

Comment: It's the same story with taglist-plus. I have to rename the .js file to .html or else it won't recognize any tags.

Answer (score 0):

- What is the filetype (`:set ft?`) of the file you are working on?
- Do you have `ctags` and/or `jsctags` installed and working?

  Do `$ ctags -R .` and/or `$ jsctags .` executed from where you put your JavaScript files create a `tags` file?

  If yes, what does it contain?
- If you are using `jsctags`, is it current? What about nodejs?

Comment: Filetype is javascript if the extension is .js and html if the extension is .html. ctags and jsctags are both installed and working. ctags -R . completes without any error messages but jsctags seems to hang. If I do jsctags on a .js file it says "Error: Didnt' find a name for constructor." but not if run it on the same file with the filename extension renamed to html. I recently installed jsctags so it should be current.

Comment: You have to split your problem in two as `jsctags` and `ctags` are completely different pieces of software and be precise about what you are doing. In my experience, jsctags doesn't work at all against anything other than plain .js files, either JavaScript files with custom extensions or HTML files with JS embeded. ctag` works in both scenarii, though. jsctags depends on nodejs which is a fast moving piece of shit. I've had troubles myself with jsctags before, that I've "solved" by installing another version of nodejs (0.7.2-pre). Now jsctags works but its output has changed a bit and…

Comment: … it confuses the hell out of TagBar. Making the whole thing almost useless. I just saw that a fix was pulled a few months ago, I'll see if it's better. In the meantime, try upgrading nodej.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue when using `vim`, `tagbar` with `Arduino` source code in ***.ino** files while editing `Tasmota` code.

I had to realize two things:

1. Make ctags handle the new file extension (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67495267/10050838): For `ctags-universal`, create a file `~/.ctags.d/local.ctags` with `--langmap=c++:+.ino` in it.
2. Let tagbar know how to handle vim filetype `arduino` (query filetype in vim using `:set filetype?`) in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:tagbar_type_arduino = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'c++',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'd:macros:1:0',
        \ 'p:prototypes:1:0',
        \ 'g:enums',
        \ 'e:enumerators:0:0',
        \ 't:typedefs:0:0',
        \ 'n:namespaces',
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 's:structs',
        \ 'u:unions',
        \ 'f:functions',
        \ 'm:members:0:0',
        \ 'v:variables:0:0'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro'        : '::',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 'g' : 'enum',
        \ 'n' : 'namespace',
        \ 'c' : 'class',
        \ 's' : 'struct',
        \ 'u' : 'union'
    \ },
    \ 'scope2kind' : {
        \ 'enum'      : 'g',
        \ 'namespace' : 'n',
        \ 'class'     : 'c',
        \ 'struct'    : 's',
        \ 'union'     : 'u'
    \ }
\ }
```

Find a how-to and this definition in `:help tagbar -> tagbar-extend`. Javascript and other definitions are given in `~/.vim/bundle/tagbar/autoload/tagbar/types/uctags.vim`

There may be other ways to do this. It works for me (tm).

The only thing left to do: reopen the `*.ino` source file, hit `<F8>` to show your tagbar.

HTH