# Adding new lang to ctags does not work

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am trying to add *.volt* extension to ctags language map, but it keep ignoring *.volt* file. This is content of my *.ctags* file:

```
--recurse=yes
--tag-relative=yes
--exclude=*.git*
--exclude=.DS_Store

--langmap=html:+.volt
```

When I do ***ctags --list-maps*** I will see .volt files being included in HTML:

```
HTML     *.htm *.html *.volt
```

But still when I run ctags, it completely ignores *.volt* files. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons for the unexpected behavior are most likely:

1. You are not using currently latest version 5.8 of **Exuberant Ctags**, but a version before 5.6.
2. Your `.ctags` file has `--langmap=html:+.volt` at end of file with no line termination.

Read the full story below on why I think those 2 reasons result in the unexpected behavior of **Ctags** on your computer.

---

I looked on your problem on Windows first using older version 5.5.4 of **Exuberant Ctags** installed with text editor [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com) and later also with version 5.8 downloaded directly from [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) project page.

I created a copy of one of my HTML projects with just 1 *.html file in parent directory of the test project, 3 *.html files in a subdirectory and two more *.html files also in the subdirectory with file extension changed from `html` to `volt` on both files which were just copies of 2 of the 3 *.html files in this subdirectory.

Next I created in parent directory of the project a `ctags.conf` file and copied the few lines you posted into this file. Additionally I inserted at top a line with `--verbose` as this is useful on looking for problems like that.

And last I copied `ctags.exe` (first v5.5.4, later v5.8) also into the test project directory just for making it easier to run it from command line.

I opened a command prompt window in test project directory and executed

```
ctags.exe -f test.tag --options=ctags.conf
```

I could see on verbose output that both *.volt files were opened for processing and created `test.tag` contained also all the tags from the 2 *.volt files, the same tags as the 2 *.html files from which the *.volt files were copied before.

So what could be the problem?

I'm not only familiar with HTML. My main job is programming in C/C++. Therefore I know about an often made mistake in C source code files on reading in text files: a wrong handling of text files with no line termination on last line of the file.

And I know that some text editors like `gedit` on Linux position the caret on Ctrl+End at beginning of the line below the last line in the file even when last line of the file does not have a line termination. The caret should be in this case positioned by the text editor at end of the string on last line instead of beginning on next line beyond real end of the file. This in my point of view wrong behavior lets a user of the text editor think that the text file has a line termination also on last line of the file even if this is not true.

So I thought that you have appended `--langmap=html:+.volt` perhaps at end of the file without a line termination and `ctags.exe` does not evaluate the line in this case because of not well done text file parsing in source code. Therefore I removed the line termination in `ctags.conf` from last line containing now only `--langmap=html:+.volt`

I executed same command line as before and *AHA*, both *.volt files are ignored because of `unknown language`.

This was the time as I downloaded version 5.8 of **Ctags** for Windows and copied it into the test project directory replacing executable of version 5.5.4.

I executed the command line again with not modified `ctags.conf`. Both *.volt files were processed by **Ctags** and `test.tag` contained again the tags from both *.volt files.

Appending on last line of file `ctags.conf` again a line termination and executing the command line once more did not result in a different output. So this bug with ignoring last line of the options file if no line termination present at end of the file is fixed in version 5.8 of **Ctags**.

I searched in [Change Notes](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/news.html) of **Exuberant Ctags** for `last` and found in changes notes block for **ctags-5.6 (Mon May 29 2006)**

- Fixed problem reading last line of list file (-L) without final newline.

This is the confirmation for what I thought and could see. And of course the problem existed not only on reading the list file, but also on reading other text files like the options file, or C and Java files as the next line in the change notes informs

- Fixed infinite loop that could occur on files without final newline [C, Java].

Answer (score 1):

If the ctags binary is really `universal ctags` you need to put/link your config file here (`man ctags-universal -> FILES`):

```
~/.ctags.d/my-config.ctags
```

File extension `.ctags` is relevant.

In my case, I needed ctags to support the `arduino (.ino)` file type. Add `--langmap=c++:+.ino` to `~/.ctags.d/local.ctags` (it only symlinks to `~/.ctags` really).

Check:

```
ctags --list-maps | grep C++
C++      *.c++ *.cc *.cp *.cpp *.cxx *.h *.h++ *.hh *.hp *.hpp *.hxx *.inl *.C *.H *.CPP *.CXX *.ino
[...]
```

Notice ***.ino** at the end of the line listing known extensions.